# Are there any smartphones with good Python interpreter support?

Tags: iphone, android, python, symbian, smartphone

I'm getting a new phone and I am looking to do some programming on it. Python is my language of choice, so I was wondering what phones have support for Python interpreters.

I know, I know, "you program too much already", yeah my girlfriend says that all the time too, but I can't help it.

I'll probably do a lot of on-the-go style simple debugging, and I'd like to also get into programming some simple custom apps to streamline my smartphone workflow.

I see there is [support on Android](http://code.google.com/p/python-for-android/) through SL4A and Py4A but I couldn't figure out which version of Python it resembles. I also see that [PyS60 on Symbian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_for_S60) is available, based on 2.5.4. Also, there's a string of [Python-iPhone threads starting here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43315/can-i-write-native-iphone-apps-using-python) which were very informative but not very current. Lastly I found a [cool youtube video of a guy doing something geeky in python on his iPhone](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iFrzSDdTXkk).

Yes I am still researching on my own but I figured someone on SO might be able to give me a pointer in the right direction. Which of these options is halfway decent?

Does anyone know which of these is easiest to get started with? How about which is most powerful for development using the native smartphone capabilities? Anything

Answer (score 2):

With regards to Py4A, in view of discussion at the link below, my guess would be Py 2.7.1, 2.7.2.

http://code.google.com/p/python-for-android/issues/detail?id=10&q=python

Comment: +1 Thanks bumping for great justice. Any experience? Is it any good?

Answer (score 1):

The Nokia n900 comes with Maemo 5 Linux, and can easily run a full Debian Linux for ARM. It's not locked down in any way. I have one (in the shop, really hope they can fix it) and it's great.

Python? Basically like using it on any desktop Linux distribution.