# iPod/iPhone (jailbroken) GUI applications Python

Tags: python, user-interface, ipod

I am looking for a GUI example for iPod/iPhone (jailbroken) or some help to know where I can easily learn to make GUI applications for iPhones with Python.

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

Writing an iPhone application in any language besides Objective C, or to some extent, Lua (or HTML5) is **not easy** or recommended.

### See also:

- "[currently the only languages available to access the iPhone SDK are C/C++ and Objective C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43315/can-i-write-native-iphone-apps-using-python/43331#43331)" (2008-09)
- "[It's *now* legal to include a Python interpreter in an iPhone app.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3691655/277586)" (2011-09)
- "[It's still anything but **easy**.](http://www.saurik.com/id/5)"

If you really hate Objective C, consider [Wax](https://github.com/probablycorey/wax) or even [CoronaSDK](http://www.anscamobile.com/corona/) for Lua.  Besides that, the Interface Builder in XCode has some neat tricks. If you're willing to adopt that IDE's workflow, it's still the best/easiest way to move forward.