# how to run python in iphone?

Tags: iphone, python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I write native iPhone apps using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43315/can-i-write-native-iphone-apps-using-python)

this post [Can I write native iPhone apps using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43315/can-i-write-native-iphone-apps-using-python) is 3 years old, i think there should be a new one, since the old one comes very frequently in Google searches.

this post http://www.saurik.com/id/5 is looking good and is seems to be up to date.

i think since a lot of iPhone developers looking for an experienced advise for how to put python in your app or how to run a python script you wrote separately.

hope you can put some tips here to help us all.

Comment: This is not a forum, we don't need updated "threads" to discuss something. If you're actually making a Python iOS app and need help with a specific problem, ask that.

Comment: The best way to do this is to edit your question to ask the question you want asked (in this case, "How do I run Python in iPhone?") and then write an answer to it incorporating the answers from the post you say is up to date. Don't wait for someone else to update it - you can offer an answer to your own posts.

Comment: i think it would be very helpful if you can contribute us your knowledge and teach us.

Comment: @ZoZo123 Regardless it's not an appropriate question. Going off past questions, neither is a question of the form "How do I get started doing X?"

Comment: Although the question you link to is 3 years old, it is still open to new answers; as long as something directly answers the question it can still be added there.

Comment: where is the duplicate ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot run python on the iphone.  There maybe a way if the iphone is jailbroken but that's not something I would bet on when writing a program.

You may need to write your iphone app using objective C and, if you really want to use python, can connect it to a python web service(i.e. you run python on your server and it does the python work you want done).