# Possible to write i-phone app in python

Tags: iphone, python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I write native iPhone apps using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43315/can-i-write-native-iphone-apps-using-python)

I just googled whether it is possible to write an i-phone app in Python and
got very confusing, and not super good results.

Is it possible? And if so, what module(s) do I need to install?

Comment: Please refer this [link](http://www.saurik.com/id/5/). It might be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You would either have to write it natively in Xcode and objective-c or use something like PhoneGap http://phonegap.com/ which ends up being compiled to objective-c anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You can use PyObjC on the iPhone.

http://pyobjc.sourceforge.net/

You need to jail break your iphone for this to run.

They have a tutorial too which of course comes top of google search.

http://www.saurik.com/id/5/

Comment: Ok, if you're prepared to jailbreak

Answer (score 0):

Technically for jail broken iPhone yes as you can do anything. However for a mainstream app that passes the app store rules  you need to use objective C.